# Wrapping the output of a .each method in ruby with HTML tags

Tags: html, ruby, sinatra

I have a simple.each method that outputs url's from a psql database and i am rendering them on a .erb file in Sequel. I have some nice CSS that styles them like Pinterest in 'pins' and in columns. This method relies on each 'pin' being inside an individual   wrapper. So my ruby looks like;

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="columns">
    <div class="pin">
      <% @videos.each do |video| %>
      <a href="/videos/<%=video['id']%>"><%= video['title'] %> <%= video['url'] %> </a>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a method that i can put inside my block to wrap each output in the div class?

Comment: why don't you just move the div tag inside your each block? If that's not it, I don't understand your question. Could you provide desired HTML output?

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="columns">
    <% @videos.each do |video| %>
      <div class="pin">
        <a href="/videos/<%=video['id']%>"><%= video['title'] %> <%= video['url'] %> </a>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```